# automate a script in bash

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have two programs `foo.py and bar.py`

Running `foo.py creates a file foo_cur_timestamp.txt` 
and `bar.py creates a file bar_cur_timestamp.txt`

These are actually tweets collected using twitter streaming api's
The tweets are flushed to the file so that number of lines in the file are ever growing (and not like the file is written in the end but its written in realtime)

Now.. what happens sometimes foo.py and bar.py collects 40k tweets it hits the twitter api ceiling and twitter throws an error and I have to restart the program again (`%python foo.py or bar.py`) but its only sometimes..

Running that program will create a new file (as cur_timestamp is now different)..

I want to automate these steps..

1) Every 1 min count the number of lines in the file currently being written (basically files with prefix `foo_ .....txt and bar_....txt`)

2) If the number of lines in file hits 40k and its not growing.. then start the relevant program again.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*/1 * * *　×　wc -l foo*txt |awk '{ if( $2=="total" && $1 >=400000) { system("python foo.py") } }'
*/1 * * *　×　wc -l bar*txt |awk '{ if( $2=="total" && $1 >=400000) { system("python bar.py") } }'
```